# Obtain torch.tensor from string of floats

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

We can convert 1 dimensional array of floats, stored as a space separated numbers in text file, in to a numpy array or a  torch tensor as follows.

```
line = "1 5 3 7 4"
np_array = np.fromstring(line, dtype='int', sep=" ")

np_array
>> array([1, 5, 3, 7, 4])
```

And to convert above numpy array to a torch tensor, we can do following :

```
torch_tensor = torch.tensor(np_array)
torch_tensor
>>tensor([1, 5, 3, 7, 4])
```

How can I convert a string of numbers separated by space in to a `torch.Tensor` directly without 
converting them to a numpy array? We can also do this by fist splitting the string at a space, mapping them to int or float, and then feeding it to `torch.tensor`. But like `numpy`'s `fromstring`, is there any such method in pytorch?

Answer (score 4):

What about

```py
x = torch.tensor(list(map(float, line.split(' '))), dtype=torch.float32)
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a solution, but, I wanted to know if there is any builtin function in pytorch, like in numpy there is `fromstring`.

Comment: @MikePatel AFAIK the closest function in pytorch you have is [`from_numpy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.from_numpy)

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch currently [has no](https://github.com/wkentaro/pytorch-for-numpy-users#from-existing-data) analogous function to numpy's `fromstring`. You can either use the numpy function itself, or by splitting and mapping as you say.